# What are the columns URCALL, RPT1CALL, and RPT2CALL in CHIRP?

Tags: radio-programming, chirp

I'm populating a CSV file to import into [CHIRP](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Download). In the [documentation](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Documentation), there's a list of [CSV columns](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/MemoryEditorColumns). However, that list doesn't cover URCALL, RPT1CALL, and RPT2CALL. Can anyone tell me what those columns are for and how they're used in radios?

Comment: Just a helpful tip for anyone that might be reading this and is new to CHIRP. At least what follows is my experience with a Baofeng. You should not start with a CSV or blank file in CHIRP, you should start by downloading your radio data into CHIRP first and saving that img file. This may change what columns and options are available to you and will save you a lot of time (although you will still get those 3 columns mentioned above in the CSV). You can then export the file as a CSV, edit in your spreadsheet editor of choice, re-import it, then upload to the radio. Hope this helps. 73, K0PWI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"MYCALL", "URCALL", "RPT1CALL", and "RPT2CALL" are used to program D-STAR channels in D-STAR-capable radios.  Those columns should be left blank for analog FM channels.

- MYCALL is your own call sign, eight characters maximum; "/" and suffixes are allowed, as long as everything fits in eight characters.
- URCALL is ostensibly for the call sign of the station you're trying to call, or "CQCQCQ" for calling any station or to talk on a repeater; URCALL can also be used to hold routing information or linking commands.
- RPT1 ("RPT1CALL" in CHIRP) should be set to the local repeater and module that you're trying to access.  (The setting doesn't matter for D-STAR simplex.)
- RPT2 ("RPT2CALL" in CHIRP) designates where you want your signal to be routed on your local repeater; normally RPT2 is set to the call sign of the local repeater, followed by "G".  (The setting doesn't matter for D-STAR simplex.)

Exactly how to use D-STAR is beyond the scope of a single answer.  There's an article [here](http://www.roblocher.com/whitepapers/dstar.html) that goes over the basics.